# Replace multiple parameters with same value in python string formatting

Tags: python, string

I have a huge string that looks like this:

```
100hello100string100formatting ...
```

Furthermore, `100` is a dynamic value. In the original string, there are 60 occurrences of `100`. How do I format the string so that I can pass the parameter only once?

I am currently doing the following:

```
"%dhello%dstring%dformatting%d ..." % (100, 100, 100, ...)
```

Is there any way to pass the value `100` only once so that it will take the same value for all other parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Try string [formatting](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format) ([see also PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)):

```
"{0}hello{0}string{0}formatting".format(100)
# '100hello100string100formatting'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

If you have 60 occurrences of `100`, that also means that you have 60 words in your string. Most likely you got those words from somewhere, for instance from a file, or from a database or from user input.

Assuming that you can get all of those words into a list, why not just join the elements of the list, instead of going to the trouble of typing all the words out?

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'string', 'formatting']
>>> '100'.join(words)
hello100string100formatting
```

For this to work, your dynamic value `100` must be a string, so if it's stored as a number, you'll need to convert it first:

```
>>> num = 100
>>> str(num).join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"%dhello%dstring%dformatting" % (*[100]*3,)`

Basically, you create a temp list containing the values you need (`[100]`), multiply that by how many times you need it (`*3`) and prepend that with `*` so that you unpack the list

Answer (score -1):

**Just a suggestion**

First create a template string in which you put some special character in place where the dynamic value should be. 
*Example* : ##hello##string##formatting

Then make a function that replace the ## in the string with given parameter using regex.

**Code**

```
def getString(value, string) :
    newString = string.replace('##', str(value))
    return newString

template = '##hello##string##formatting'
replaceHundred = getString(100, template)
replaceTwoHundred = getString(200, template)
.
.
replacedString = getString( anyValue , template)
```